# How to add characters to reach the maximum size of a char[]

Tags: c, char

I have the following part of code :

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    printf("Student %d\n",i+1);
    printf("Enter name : ");
    scanf("%s",&(student+i)->name);
    fflush(stdin);

    lengthName = strlen((student+i)->name);
    while(lengthName !='\0')
    {

    }}
```

when the length is shorter than 10, it will add hyphens until reaching the maximum size.
Ex : John =>> 6 hyphens will be added

I know how to do it in csharp but can't figure it out in c. 
Could some of you give me some lights please?

PS : Oh yes the variable name is char name[10+1] and it a part of the structure called student.

Comment: When you print out the resulting student names, do you want the `-` characters to show up?

Comment: @Matt: No I don't want strcat().
@birryree: yes I want these characters to show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is so simple that it seems like I must be missing something.

```
lengthName = strlen(student[i].name);
while (lengthName < 10)
  student[i].name[lengthName++] = '-';
student[i].name[lengthName] = '\0';
```

Perhaps you are confused by C#'s (presumed) possession of a first-class string type?  No such thing in C, only bare arrays of characters; which is at once tedious (you have to do all the memory management yourself) and liberating (as you see above).

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
// Pre-fills with hyphens.
memset(student[i].name, '-', sizeof(student[i].name) - 1);
scanf("%10s", student[i].name);
```

Comment: `fgets` is better, but will output `'\n'` and `'\0'` bytes.  You can do `memset` on the remainder after the `fgets` to fix this.

Comment: Maintainability? (what if size of student[i].name changes?)

Comment: `fflush` is not defined on input streams; you can't clear the input buffer this way.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(lengthName < 10)  
{  
    student[i]->name[lengthName++] = '-'; // add this line  
}  
student[i]->name[lengthName] = 0;  // and this line
```

Comment: I don't understand the last line. Why do affect 0 to name[lengthName] ? Shouldn't it be '\0'?

Comment: Character constants in C are treated as numbers, so `0` and `'\0'` are two different ways to write the same number.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
while (lengthName < 10)
{
    (student+i)->name[lengthName++] = '-';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `char name[10 + 1];` variable is obviously 11 bytes long. Adding anything more than 11 bytes will cause a buffer overflow.

This is where the buffer overflow might happen:

`scanf("%s",&(student+i)->name);`

Your hyphens feature can come after you fixed this possible buffer overflow issue.

### Fixing the buffer overflow

One easy way to fix this sort of problem is to have scanf itself limit the number of chars to read:

```
// read only 10 chars, since `name` can only 
// hold 10 chars, plus the extra NULL char
scanf("%10s", &(student+i)->name);
```

### Pre-filling with hyphens

Finally, after you took care of your memory issue, you can go ahead and pre-fill your string before overwriting it with the actual student data.

```
// pre-fill your data with hypens.
memset((student+i)->name, '-', sizeof((student+i)->name) - 1);

// read only 10 chars, since `name` can only 
// hold 10 chars, plus the extra NULL char
scanf("%10s", &(student+i)->name);
```

Comment: Maintainability? (what if size of student[i].name changes?)

Comment: @user: I'm here to fix his specific problem. If he's using an 11 byte long variable, I wrote the best solution to be applied with this sort of space. Maybe he can't use more than 11 bytes, who knows. Of course it would be more maintainable if the space allocated was bigger, but that's not part of the issue.

Comment: I'm not pointing out the fact that it's a small buffer to work with, all I'm saying is don't repeat yourself http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself. `name` has already been defined as 11 characters long, why do you need to repeat yourself and say `%10s`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the link about the "Don't repeat yourself" concept, I'm quite aware of what it is. In this case, however, it has nothing to do with repeating yourself. If you don't supply the `%10s`, scanf() will copy any amount of bytes to the `name` variable, causing a possible buffer overflow. Having the `%10s` tells scanf() to only read 10 bytes, which is the maximum allowed by the variable `name`.

Comment: That's exactly the point. In this case, you are forced to repeat the size of `name`. If the length of name changes to 15, you must go back and change it to `%14s`. If it changes again to 25, you gotta go back and change it to `%24s`. If you forget to change it both places, you get random errors. If you hand the project off to somebody and forget to tell them to change it both places, they get random errors.

Comment: user: My question was only to show how to fix the buffer overflow problem. Optimization is up to yourself.

Comment: There's no way to avoid this particular repetitiveness in C, because `scanf`, unlike `printf`, does not allow you to state the size of the buffer except inline in the format string.  (`"%*s"` means "scan and discard", not "scan taking buffer size from argument list".)  If you say this is a reason to not use scanf, I will agree with you.

Comment: All I am saying is that there are solutions here which allow you to not repeat yourself for this particular problem; this one does not. I don't mean to make a major issue out of it (because it's not), I was just pointing out the fact that this is less maintainable than other suggested alternatives.

Comment: @user, which other alternatives? None of them seem to deal with the buffer overflow issue.

Answer (score 0):

Modified version of @kotlinski's idea:

```
#define NAME_SIZE 10

fgets(student[i].name, NAME_SIZE, stdin);
lengthName = strlen(student[i].name);
if (lengthName > 0 && student[i].name[lengthName-1] == '\n') {
    --lengthName;
}
if (lengthName < NAME_SIZE) {
    memset(student[i].name + lengthName, '-', NAME_SIZE - lengthName);
    student[i].name[NAME_SIZE] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fgets()` to read the input, with the understanding that it will save the newline character to the buffer if there's room; you'll have to add some special handling for that.

Note that the behavior of `fflush()` is **not defined** for input streams; you cannot clear unwanted input by calling `fflush(stdin);`.

Then it's a matter of setting the remaining characters to hyphens.

```
if (fgets(students[i].name, sizeof students[i].name, stdin) != NULL)
{
  size_t max = sizeof students[i].name - 1;
  size_t len = 0;

  char *newline = strchr(students[i].name, '\n');
  if (newline)
    *newline = 0; // clear out newline
  else
  {
    while (fgetc(stdin) != '\n') // clear out remaining input; 
                                 // name potentially truncated
      ;
  }

  // pad remainder with hyphens
  len = strlen(students[i].name);
  while (len < max)
    students[i].name[len++] = '-';
  students[i].name[max] = 0;
}
```